# Would anyone respond / share who is working in the real estate space with Cardano?

Tags: nft, payment

Who is working within real estate on blockchain, and especially within ADA/Cardano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/essential-cardano/blob/main/essential-cardano-list.md) is a comprehensive list of Cardano partners.

It's not immediately obvious which/if any are real estate projects.